# knockout.js afterRender does not work in a jquery pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

```
<div data-bind="style: { display: !koIsHidden() ? 'inline-block' : 'none'}">
<button id="hideButton" type="button" title="Hide" onclick="javascript:openJuiPopup('#hidePopup')" style="background: none; border: none">
    <i id="hideCross" class="fa fa-2x fa-times" data-bind="attr: { 'data-applicationKey': application.applicationKey }"></i>
</button>
</div>
```

This button loads a pop-up that looks like this

[image]

The code for the popup looks like:

```
<div id="hidePopup" class="popup ui-content" data-role="popup">
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: previewApplications(), afterRender: renderPopup} -->
    <form id="hider" style="display:inline;" method="post" data-bind="attr: {action: '@(MVC.GetLocalUrl(MVC.HireOrgJobApplication.ViewApplication(Model.CurrentOrganization.CustomUrl, Model.Job.JobKey, "xxx/ajax-hide")))'.replace('xxx', application.applicationKey)}">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="hidden" name="ApplicationKey" data-bind="attr:{ value : application.applicationKey }" />
        <input type="hidden" name="HideReasonId" value="7" />


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger jui-tooltip" data-bind="text: application.hideButtonSendRejectionInsteadOfHide === true ? 'Reject' : 'Hide', attr: { title: application.hideButtonSendRejectionInsteadOfHide === false ? 'Reject' : 'Hide'}"></button>

    </form>
    <!--/ko-->
</div>
```

And the js code that calls it:

```
            $("#hidePopup").dialog({
                dialogClass: "no-close",
                position: { my: "bottom", at: "bottom", of: $("#hideCross"), collision: "none" },
                autoOpen: false,
                draggable: true,
            }).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
```

The detail isn't that important, but one thing important in this code is

```
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: previewApplications(), afterRender: renderPopup} -->
```

Due to the afterRender feature of knockout js, this should loop through elements in previewApplications() and run the function renderPopup.

The renderPopup looks like

```
                self.renderPopup = function (element, data) {

                    $(element).find("form#hider").ajaxForm(function () {
                        alert("heyyyyy");
                    });

                };
```

This should just simply find a form with id = hider, and run alert("heyyyy").
But it doesn't work.

Notice that afterRender worked totally fine when i put it outside of the popup.

Please help!

EDIT:

I can add more info to this question.
It's not about afterRender, but the ajaxForm just does not work for the popup.
Any idea?

EDIT2:

```
                self.renderApplication = function (element, data) {

                    filter: ($(element).filter("form#hider")[0]).ajaxForm(function () {
                        data.koIsHidden(true);
                    });

                };
```

I tried this and

```
                    $(element).filter(("form#hider")[0]).ajaxForm(function () {
                        data.koIsHidden(true);
                    });
```

The code above gives me the error that i wrote in the comment, and the second one gives me no error, but still doesnt catch the renderApplication function.

Comment: If you have `form id="hider"` inside a `ko foreach`, you're going to create multiple forms with the same ID.  Probably not the source of your problem, but it is a problem.

Comment: From de jQuery documentation, `find()`  "..Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements...".  You need to replace it with `filter`:  `($(element).filter("form#hider")[0]).ajaxForm (...`.

Comment: i fixed it like EDIT2, but it says "Cannot read property 'ajaxForm' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Call renderPopup like a function - afterRender: renderPopup() or you may have to try $root.renderPopup() or $parent.renderPopup().